# Converter form Json data to NGSI-V2 data

Tags: json, fiware-orion

For one of my use case, I need a Json to NGSI-v2 converter. Is there any converter that convert Json data to NGSI-v2 data?

Comment: What "json" means in this context? JSON is just a data encoding syntax, you can use virtually *unlimited* ways of encoding information in JSON (in fact, NGSIv2 is one of these ways). Could you edit your question post to elaborate a bit more, please? Maybe providing examples of the source JSON you want to covert.

Comment: Any type of json that contain some ID and type. This kind of converter is important if you want to convert any json into NGSIV2 or if you want to integrate any fiware GE with real time IoT plateform

Comment: Could you edit your question post to include an example of such document? Maybe in that case I can provide some ideas...